# What would you recommend for hosting 10+ individual wordpress websites?

Tags: multisite, hosting

I have about 10+ individual Wordpress websites and another Wordpress MU website with about 24 users.

I am looking for a good web hosting company / plan to host this. The numbers may grow in the next years, so I need a long-term service for this, possibly affordable and with good support.

Basically what I am searching for is:
- very good uptime;
- security, shared ssl certificate;
- unlimited domains, bandwidth, space;

So what would you recommend based on your experience? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to your sites quantity and requirements, I will recommend you cloud hosting, as it is fully flexible you can upgrade it any time,

Or you can go with VPS.

For cloud rackspace is the best, and it has good uptime + Live Chat support(I have never used, but heard a lot good reviews about it)

And for VPS, I am using intovps.com, they are cheap and good uptime.
But its fully unmanaged